# Django Model - Cost of inheritance

Tags: python, django, performance, inheritance

We have django project, and we found that some models become huge.

```
class BigModel(models.Model):
    """
    Large set of fields
    """
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    fieldN = models.IntegerField()
    """
    Large set of methods
    """
    def method1(self): pass
    def method2(self): pass
    def method3(self): pass
    ...
    def methodN(self): pass
```

I want to divide `BigModel` class into smaller classes with list of methods. But in whole project we have references to `BigModel` class.

So my idea is to do it by small steps:

1. Divide `BigModel` class into `BigFields` and `BigMethods`. Inherit
   `BigMethods` from `BigFields`. Inherit `BigModel` from `BigMethods`.
2. By creating proxy models and replacing references to `BigModel` with them in code - reduce size of `BigMethods` class.

So, at the moment of refactoring our code will look like this:

```
class BigFields(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    """
    Large set of fields
    """
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    fieldN = models.IntegerField()

class BigMethods(BigFields):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    """
    Large set of methods
    """
    def method1(self): pass
    def method2(self): pass
    def method3(self): pass
    ...
    def methodN(self): pass

class BigModel(BigMethods):
    pass
```

- How it will affect performance?
- What is the cost of one level of inheritance in python?
- Does metaclasses affects cost of inheritance?

Comment: If you need to talk about "fieldn" then it's time to normalize further.

Comment: I assumed that method1, method2, etc were just for example purposes, not the real names of his fields/methods

Comment: @jterrace: Not *quite* what I was getting at...

Comment: ah, I see. I didn't think he actually had N sequential fields

Comment: I don't have sequential fields, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

If you have sequential fields like this in your model the solution is not inheritance, but breaking out these fields into a separate model and creating a one-to-many relationship. It's hard to make the point with your example models, so I'll use one from a project I was working on.

The original model looked something like this:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    section_1_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    section_1_content = models.TextField()
    section_2_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    section_2_content = models.TextField()
    section_3_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    section_3_content = models.TextField()
    ...
```

Obviously this was a nightmare to maintain, so I changed it to the following:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Section(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='sections')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField()
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
        order_with_respect_to = 'page'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sequence was for example :) I have a lot of fields with different names, and db is relatively normalized. Problem is that I have a lot of methods, and I haven't known about proxy models well on start of project - so my model classes are too clever. I want to reduce it.

Comment: Sorry. Well, I'll leave my answer for posterity, but there shouldn't be any issues with doing the way you describe in your question. Abstract models are closer to mixins than true inheritance. Your database will remain the same and there's not really any performance hits to speak of.